# What are the differences between two of these?

Tags: python, regex

```
find = re.compile(r'die\ area \s+ = \s+ (%d)')
```

What's the difference between `'\ '` and `' '`?

Comment: Well, in raw strings, the former is a backlash followed by a space, while the latter is merely a space.

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think there's any difference in terms of regex. Can't seem to find any mentioned in the [python regex spec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: But in a regex, those are the same; the backslash is merely redundant.  The only time you need to escape a space is when you're using free-spacing mode (`re.X`) and you want to include a literal space character.

Comment: @AlanMoore your comment looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score -1):

RegEx101.com agrees. Both match a literal ' '